# XSLT number() function is giving Scientific Notation output in Mule ESB

Tags: xslt, mule, xslt-2.0

I'm using the XSLT transformer component in Mule project.
Look at my XSLT code:

```
<id>
  <xsl:value-of select="number($candidateID)" />
</id>
```

`$candidateID` is "1030320" as string value, but the XSLT output is `<id>1.030307E6</id>`.

I need the output to be `<id>1030320<id>`

```
<id>
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number($candidateID, '#')" />
</id>
```

In this case, if the `$candidateID` value is greater than 17, it adds 0 to the remaining value. I don't understand what's wrong.

**EDIT:**

XSLT-2.0 casting does work:

```
<id>
  <xsl:value-of select="$candidateID cast as xs:integer" />
</id>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor? An why do you need to use the `number() `function here?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Edited my question.
I'm using this in one of the Java ESB called mule. I'm converting to xml to java object